# jQuery animate to next image in div

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, jquery-animate

I've got some images within a `div` which i'm trying to when I click the next button animate to the next one in the div

In this div I also have my previous and next button which I obviously don't want to animate to.

```
<div class="work">
<a href="#" class="rightButton"><img src="http://www.jamietaylor-webdesign.co.uk/images/home/right.png" /></a>
<a href="#" class="leftButton"><img src="http://www.jamietaylor-webdesign.co.uk/images/home/left.png" /></a>
<a href="#" class="1"><img class="topLeft" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/JQFbb.jpg" /></a>
<a href="#" class="2"><img class="topRight" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/l5OPs.jpg" /></a>
<a href="#" class="3"><img class="bottomLeft" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/okxQz.jpg" /></a>
<a href="#" class="4"><img class="bottomRight" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/4uPHw.jpg" /></a>
</div>
```

My jQuery which doesn't actually work

```
    // prevent click jump
$('a').click(function() {
    return false;
});

// do work
$('.work > .leftButton').click(function() {

    //animate to previous image in the list
    $(this).siblings().prev().show();

});

$('.work > .rightButton').click(function() {

    //animate to next image in the list
    $(this).siblings().next().show();

});
```

Is there a way to animate to the next image that doesn't have the class of `leftButton` or `rightButton`.

Also is there a way so that if i'm on the first image it will go to the last image in the div?

[Here's a link to the jsFiddle i've got](http://jsfiddle.net/ChiBlaaa/6TLK2/2/)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Edited to scroll images into view:**

This requires some change to your markup, but will allow images to scroll left/right:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="work">
    <div class="nav">
        <a href="#" class="rightButton"><img src="http://www.jamietaylor-webdesign.co.uk/images/home/right.png" /></a>
        <a href="#" class="leftButton"><img src="http://www.jamietaylor-webdesign.co.uk/images/home/left.png" /></a>       
    </div>
    <div class="scroller">
        <div class="items">
            <a href="#" class="1"><img class="topLeft" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/JQFbb.jpg" /></a>
            <a href="#" class="2"><img class="topRight" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/l5OPs.jpg" /></a>
            <a href="#" class="3"><img class="bottomLeft" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/okxQz.jpg" /></a>
            <a href="#" class="4"><img class="bottomRight" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/4uPHw.jpg" /></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Relevant CSS:**

```
div.work { background-color: #ddd; height:240px; position: relative; width:300px;  margin-left:10px}
div.items { position:relative; width: 1000em; height: 240px; }
div.scroller { overflow: hidden; width: 300px; height: 100%; }
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$('.work .leftButton').click(function() {
    var $items = $(".items");
    if ($items.position().left === 0) {
        $items.css("left", "-300px");
        $items.children("a:last").prependTo($items);
    }
    $(".items").animate({
        left: "+=300px"
    });
});

$('.work .rightButton').click(function() {
    var $items = $(".items");
    if ($items.position().left === -900) {
        $items.css("left", "-600px");
        $items.children("a:first").appendTo($items);
    }

    $(".items").animate({
        left: "-=300px"
    });

});
```

Basically what's going on is that there's a fixed viewport (`scroller`) with hidden overflow that contains a really long `div` (`items`) containing all the images.  The `items` div is just animated on every click of the next/previous buttons.

The tricky part is moving the last element to the front and vice/versa when the end of the line of images is reached.  This is determined by hardcoded values, but could probably be improved using an exact calculation.

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/andrewwhitaker/6TLK2/3/

Comment: @Andrew Whitaker - that's just what I had in mind - i'd like a slide left/slide right animation which hopefully I can incorporate into what you've given me - is there a way so that when I get to the last one it will go back to the start? Thanks

Comment: @Jamie: Sure thing--See my updated answer.  I'll also work on getting it to slide in from the left/right, that's a little more involved.

Comment: @Jamie: Please take a look at my updated answer.  I've gotten it to slide images in left and right in a circular fashion.

Comment: +1 for a good solution, and going that little bit further. =)

Answer (score 2):

If you remove 'display:none' from the CSS (on img tags), here is the code that works with your markup and rotates images on right and left buttons:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
    $(function() {
        $("div.work >a:gt(2)").hide();

        $(".rightButton").click(function () {

            if ($("div.work >a:last").is(":visible"))
            {
                $("div.work >a:gt(1)").hide();
                $("div.work >a:eq(2)").show();
            } else {
                $("div.work >a:visible:gt(1)").hide().next().show();
            }
        });

        $(".leftButton").click(function () {

            if ($("div.work >a:eq(2)").is(":visible"))
            {
                $("div.work >a:gt(1)").hide();
                $("div.work >a:last").show();
            } else {
                $("div.work >a:visible:gt(1)").hide().prev().show();
            }
        });

    });



//-->
</script>
```

Comment: OP = original poster (aka Jamie Taylor). I copied your Javascript and pasted it into Jamie's jsFiddle and it did not work.

Comment: @Nimrod Thanks! I just tried on jsFiddle and my JS works if you clear CSS on right top box. So, there is something in CSS that is conflicting. In my testing, I didn't use any CSS.

Comment: @Nimrod: The JS works if you just remove 'display:none' from CSS because in JS I am hiding/unhiding anchors not the images.

Comment: @Ritesh - Thanks this works if I take the display:none css out - Thanks

Comment: @Ritesh: Then, you should probably clarify that in your answer because you stated "works with your given markup" when it does not.

Comment: @Nimrod You are right. I meant the html markup. Also I missed the jsFiddle part. This is the first time I used jsFiddle. I learnt something new today (OP and jsFiddle)! Thanks!

Comment: Thanks Ritesh. I originally voted this answer down, but I'll gladly remove it if you mention the CSS fix as part of the answer.